# It is possible to use SNMP in communication between two applications

Tags: .net, windows, snmp

I have a question in SNMP. I have a chat application, which works in Local Area Network.  The chat application is developed in vb.net. It has a central server and clients installed in all other computers.
Currently it is deployed on small number (50) of clients and we are checking the status (online/offline) of clients using ping.
I know this is not a efficient method, so I am planning to implement a method which works in large number of clients.(500- 1000 clients).

So my question is can I use SNMP to establish communication between two applications ? or to check status of clients?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with SNMP and SNMP is not designed for chat applications. You probably should check other protocols or frameworks, such as WebSocket and SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

**SNMP** stands for **S**imple **N**etwork **M**anagement **P**rotocol. This means the purpose of this protocol is to manage stuff over network (printers/routers/ sometimes applications)

Of course, you can find if an host is online, you even could do a chat application using only SNMP *(but SNMP is not meant to do that, so that would be doing things the hard way.)*

I think you have a conception problem. You already have a client-server connection (you use to transfer chat data). Maybe you can check if the client is connected ? or add an hidden "IMCONNECTED" message so your server can know the client is connected